# Structure Typecasting

Tags: c, types

I have a

```
structure {
    int a;
    char b;
} st;
```

Is there a way to typecast the structure member `st.a`?
Because in few places I want it as `int` and in few places I want it as `Char*`

Comment: Shouldn't they be two different structs in that case?

Comment: Use, the codeparts appearing as flower brackets before posting any codes or code related keywords.

Comment: Beware: on most 64-bit platforms you're likely to encounter, an `int` is not big enough to hold a `char*` or any other pointer type, so using the same field to hold values of both types probably won't turn out well.

Comment: Do you mean you want to interpret an integer as a char pointer?

Comment: Changed it to `C` because the OP rejected a C++-only answer.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I suggest to use a [union](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y9zewe0d%28v=vs.80%29.aspx):

```
struct {
  union {
    int a;
    char *ptr;
  } u;
  char b;
} st;
```

Under the assumption that `sizeof(int) == sizeof(char*)` holds, you can access the same value in memory by either using `st.u.a` or `st.u.ptr`.

For what it's worth, consider using `size_t` instead of `int` as the type of the `a` field. That way, your code will still be correct in 64bit builds (in which an `int` may still be 32bit but a pointer is 64bit).

Comment: @Jonathan: Thanks for clarifying this; I fixed the code sample. For what it's worth, Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 (the compiler I have access to right now) happily accepts anonymous unions in C code, too.

Answer (score 1):

What you want is called [unions](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/other_data_types/).